# bash array not working

Tags: arrays, bash, fastq

I am rather new to bioinformatic but trying my best to learn. I am running into an issue and I was hoping someone would know what to do, and explain me how bash tool for multiple file is actually working.

I have a folder with 160 RNAseq libraries unzip just look like `name.fastq`.
I want to run `cutadapt` (a software which will remove all the adapters sequence from my libraries) on all of them at the same time; so, for one library, the command looks just like this:

```
python2.6 /imports/home/w/workshop/oibc2013/oibc1/Apps/cutadapt-1.2.1/bin/cutadapt -a name_adapter input_file.fastq > out
```

So I tried to make a bash array loop to be able to do it on all 160 files I have, but it still does not work.

```
!/bin/bash

. $HOME/.bashrc
my_array=(*.fastq)
echo ${myarray["SGE_TASK_ID"-1]}
python2.6 \
  /imports/home/w/workshop/oibc2013/oibc1/Apps/cutadapt-1.2.1/bin/cutadapt \
  -a CTGTCTCTTATACACATCT \
  -b AATTGCAGTGGTATCAACGCAGAGCGGCCGC \
  -b GCGGCCGCTCTGCGTTGATACCACTGCAATT \
  -b AAGCAGTGGTATCAACGCAGAGTACATGGG \
  -b CCCATGTACTCTGCGTTGATACCACTGCTT \
  inputs.$SGE_TASK_ID \
  results.$SGE_TASK_ID]}
```

Comment: Lines too long to be readable without scrolling are generally bad news; it's worth formatting your code so folks can actually read it.

Comment: ...also, you really need to be quoting your expansions. `"$foo"`, not just bare `$foo`, or you end up with odd bugs when dealing with unusual inputs.

Comment: Anyhow -- the original code creates an array, but it doesn't have any loop to iterate over it. It also doesn't ever actually set SGE_TASK_ID anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than an array, you just want a loop. In this case, since you're matching a glob pattern (`*.fastq`), a `for ... in` loop would make sense.

The general syntax is `for variable_name in list_of_words; do something_with $variable_name; done;`. In your case:

```
#!/bin/bash
. $HOME/.bashrc

path=/imports/home/w/workshop/oibc2013/oibc1/Apps/cutadapt-1.2.1/bin
for file in *.fastq
do
     python2.6 "$path"/cutadapt -a name_adapter "$file" > "$file.out"
done
```

Comment: ...to be fair, he could have iterated over the array the same way (there's just no reason to): `for file in "${my_array[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Very true, and a good example of how you would use an array if you had one for some other reason. :)